# Yii captcha not refreshing client validation on refreshing captcha

Tags: php, validation, captcha, yii2

Yii captcha works well for the first time the page loads, But when I click "get new code" button captcha refreshes but the client side validation is not updated, it validates on captcha code which was loaded first on the page, Is there some solution to update client side captcha validation ?

Comment: try in site controller
 public function actions()
 {
  return [
   'error' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
   ],
   'captcha' => [
    'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
    'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
   ],
  ];
 }

Comment: I have the same issue, the answer above does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when tried to use Captcha in a **module**.
The problem was related to bug in Yii2 core. Here is the bug itself https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10385. v2.0.8 has this issue resolved. So just try to update your Yii2 version. `composer update yiisoft/yii2` or `php composer.phar update yiisoft/yii2`

Answer (score 0):

work for me :-

```
function capcha() {   
    var response    =   grecaptcha.getResponse();   
    if(response.length === 0){    
        alert(" Please verify captcha.");   
        return false;   
    } else {      
        $("#loginform").submit();  
    }
}
```

apply onclick event on submit.